# Zend Framework 2: Ho to set Cookie in Module.php to access from other Modules

Tags: zend-framework2

I have created a Project to display adverts. Each Advert has a Location.

Currently a list if adverts are displayed. I would now like a list of locations in my `layout.phtml` and after a click on the location the adverts should be filtered.

To achieve this I have created a new Module called Geolocation. I have then created two new view helpers; one to show all the Locations and the other is to display the name of the chosen Location, which is stored in a Cookie.

When you click on a location in the list you access a AJAX request is made to the Geolocation Controller. The controller calls a method in a service to store the location in the cookie.

I am now changing my SQL Queries and Repositories in my Advert Module to accept location if it is set:

```
public function countAdvertsByCategory($location=false)
```

Normally, I would add `$location = $_COOKIE['ChosenCounty']` in my advert controller, but I am sure there is a better way.

I would have thought that I can maybe add this in the `module.php` from the Geolocation Module. If that Module has included the variable, `$location` will be set with the cookie value and otherwise it will just be ignored.

Is that the right way or what is the best practice? And how would I do that?

**UPDATE**

I have now changed my Factory:

```
namespace Application\Navigation;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MyNavigationFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
  public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
  { 
    // previous without Geolocation
    $navigation =  new MyNavigation();
    return $navigation->createService($serviceLocator); 

    $location = $serviceLocator->get('Geolocation\Service\Geolocation');
    $navigation =  new MyNavigation($location);
    return $navigation->createService($serviceLocator);
  }
```

BUT, if I would now remove my Geolocation Module, than the Factory in my Application Module to create my Navigation would fail, meaning my Factory is now dependent of this new Module which I did not want. How could I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the cookie value as a 'service' to the service manager. Whenever you need the `$location` you would then just retrieve it from the service manager.

Create a factory that accesses the required cookie variable.

```
namespace GeoLocation\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class GeoLocationFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $request = $serviceLocator->get('Request');
        $cookies = $request->getHeaders()->get('cookie');

        return isset($cookies->location) ? $cookies->location : false;
    }
}
```

Then register it with the service manager in `module.config.php`.

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'GeoLocation\Service\GeoLocation' => 'GeoLocation\Service\GeoLocationFactory',
    ],
],
```

Then you can update your `AdvertService` to require the value

```
class AdvertService
{
    protected $location;

    public function __construct($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;
    }

    public function getAdvertsByCategory()
    {
        return $this->repository->countAdvertsByCategory($this->location);
    }
}
```

You can then create a new `AdvertServiceFactory` that will fetch and inject the service into the `AdvertService::__construct` using

```
$serviceManager->get('GeoLocation\Service\GeoLocation');
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I will try your solution, but I am not sure I will manage it, looking at the way I have structured my Sourcecode so far.... all very confusing and I have to admit it has not clicked yet.